# How do I display the child elements of Firebase Realtime Database in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an ecommerce application and I want to display the list of products in an order done by the customer. I am able to display the details of the order but unable to display the list of products in that order.

Please see the image below. I want to display those 2 products with their details in a RecyclerView.

[image]

Here is my code

```
databaseReference.child("Orders").child(shopId).child(orderId).orderByChild(orderId).equalTo(orderId)
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<PlaceOrder> placeOrderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            placeOrderArrayList.add(ds.getValue(PlaceOrder.class));
        }
        UserOrderDetailsAdapter userOrderDetailsAdapter = new UserOrderDetailsAdapter(UserOrderDetailsActivity.this,placeOrderArrayList);
        productsRv.setAdapter(userOrderDetailsAdapter);
        userOrderDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order on the child named "orderId", not on the value of the `orderId` variable:

```
databaseReference.child("Orders").child(shopId).child(orderId)
   .orderByChild("orderId").equalTo(orderId)
```

---

Your data structure is not following the best practices outlined in the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data). I specifically recommend reading about [limiting nesting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flattening data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures), and considering creating two top-level nodes: `Orders` and `OrderItems`, each with the `$orderId` as keys under it. Separating the data types like that is least likely to require changing the data model down the line.